Change value back to original value in onCellValueChanged event
In my ag-grid, I am sending any inputs in my data grid back to my API to save them in the database. In case any error occurs, I want the change to be reverted back.
My problem is: That there is a loop occurring and I am not sure, if my code is the best way to achieve the API updates and reverting back to the original value.
Is it possible to update a grid value without having onCellValueChanged fired again to avoid any loops?
Is this the most elegant way to do API updates and revert back if sth fails?
async function onCellValueChanged(event: CellValueChangedEvent) {
  if (event.newValue !== event.oldValue && event.node.rowPinned !== 'top') {
    try {
      const row_id = event.data.id;
      const [metric, period] = event.column.getColId().split('_');
      if (!row_id || !metric || !period) {
        throw new Error('Invalid data');
      }
      const value = event.newValue;
      const data = {
        salesplanningrow_id: row_id,
        metric: metric,
        period: period,
        value: value
      };
      const response = await $api.salesplanning.updateSalesPlanningValue(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating data:', error);
      // Revert cell value if update failed
      event.node.setDataValue(event.column.getColId(), event.oldValue);
    }
  }
}


Another way of undoing edits in ag grid is by using the undo/redo api:
event.api.undoCellEditing();

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/undo-redo-edits/#reference-UndoRedo-undoCellEditing

That is a great point, thank you. Will need to test if I have any problems with async code and multiple data entries shortly after another, in order to undo the correct entry.
